# Linux audit logs coming in with capitalized field names (SYSCALL, AUID) Rhel 7

Tags: logs, audit

I've never encountered this before so not even sure where to start. I'm installing a log parser on a system but for some reason all audit logs are coming in with the field names capitalized. So SYSCALL=0 AUID=0 instead of syscall=0 auid=0.

This is causing major issues because the log definitions were written in such a way they're case sensitive. I can alias the field names but is there a reason this one system is reporting these fields with capital letters while all others are utilizing lowercase?